# PHP - Conseguir REQUEST_URI desde ruta actual

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de hacer un **"Framework"**, trato de conseguir la ruta que el usuario solicita desde el directorio actual usando el Mod Rewrite, con un .htaccess redirigo al usuario a index.php (Tal cual como lo hacen los frameworks conocidos), traté de usar $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] pero me muestra también el nombre del directorio, ejemplo:

Con la ruta: **http://localhost/MiFramework/MiRuta/Parametros**

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] <= MiFramework/MiRuta/Parametros
```

Y lo que quisiera obtener es:

```
MiRuta/Parametros
```

Comment: No termino de entender. Si la ruta `/MiFramework/` es parte del request, ¿por qué no se la eliminas directamente?

Comment: Porque esa ruta es el directorio dónde está alojado todo el framework, si yo quisiera hacer un sistema de rutas, sería tipo:
$route->get('/MiRuta/:parametros');
pero el REQUEST_URI me devuelve tambien el nombre del directorio actual

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo con [PATH_INFO](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php)

```
    if (isset($_GET['PATH_INFO'])){
        $peticion = explode('/', $_GET['PATH_INFO']);
    }else{
        $peticion = "Nada que mostrar";
}
```

Luego lees petición, donde tendrás en cada parte los diferentes componentes de la ruta.